# My results of MONTH table has duplicates DISTINCT will not work for me

Tags: sql-server

Query:

```
SELECT
  MONTH(orderdate) AS [Month], COUNT(orderid) AS [Number of Orders]
FROM 
  Sales.Orders
WHERE
  YEAR(orderdate) = 2007
GROUP BY
  orderdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your group by statement is wrong.

You should "GROUP BY MONTH(orderdate)"

Comment: Thank you so much now I understand the SELECT statement more and how I have everything selected is how I need to be careful to use within the query.